# Consume WCF Rest Service with multiple parameters and allow nullable parameter

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, wcf

I'm writing a web service as code below:

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    // BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
     UriTemplate = "/BudgetBalance/{userlogin}/{prnumber=null}")]
    Budget BudgetBalance(string userlogin, string prnumber);
```

As you can see at the code above, the second parameter can be filled or keeped null. By doing this, I can access the service by two different urls.

1. http://localhost:44880/Service1.svc/BudgetBalance/nurul.widiyanti
2. http://localhost:44880/Service1.svc/BudgetBalance/nurul.widiyanti/PRM-000114

If the second parameter is filled with some data, the service will return a different value. The problem is when I want to consume this webservice. Here's the code I've tried to call this service.

```
 WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
 string serviceUrl = string.Format("http://localhost:1089/Service1.svc/BudgetBalance/Nurul.Widiyanti/PRM-000114");
 byte[] data = proxy.DownloadData(serviceUrl);
 Stream _mem = new MemoryStream(data);
 var reader = new StreamReader(_mem);
 var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
 var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Budget>(result);
```

This doesn't work and make an error. I realize that this code will work if I change the `UriTemplate` within `OperationContract` to something like this:

`UriTemplate = "/BudgetBalance/{userlogin}/{prnumber}"`

But if I do this, it doesn't suit my requirement. I need to create a webservice which allow one of the parameters remains empty (null). Is this possible accomplish this requirement? If so, please guide me to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this ...

```
...
UriTemplate = "/BudgetBalance/{userlogin}")]
UriTemplate = "/BudgetBalance/{userlogin}/{prnumber}")]
Budget BudgetBalance(string userlogin, string prnumber = null) { .. }
```

Comment: Hi @war, your code didn't solve this. By using your code. If i didn't fill the second parameter. The service return endpoint not found.

Comment: You probably need a second UrlTemplate mapping (one sec i willupdate my answer)

Comment: Not possible: only 1 WebGet is allowed

Comment: Then just take the second one ... the prnumber param is made optional by the signature change,